# ng-model Values undefined when renaming from array

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that am using to create form fields in a table adding other fields that were not in the initial array. When I print out the values of this form fields after entering data I get undefined.

Here is the array

```
$scope.benefits = {
                "Emergency services": [
                    "Emergency room care",
                    "Ambulance service",
                    "Urgent care centers/facilities"
                ],
                "Laboratory services": [
                    "Lab tests & X-ray services",
                    "Imaging/diagnostics (e.g.,  MRI, CT scan, PET scan"
                ],
            };
```

Here is the plunker code
https://plnkr.co/edit/DQlXnX?p=preview

Comment: I think it's your typo problem. You printed  **$scope.benefit**  - use **$scope.benefits**

Comment: $scope.benefits prints the original array but I need it to print the original array plus the fields that I have added

Comment: why u put ng-model in td tag???

Comment: Because when am sending back the data to the api I need send that first td value too

Comment: Where you are adding your new elements?

Comment: So the first <td> data contains data from the array then the second and third  <td> elements contain input fields that I need to send back to the API as part of what the API requires

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your array declaration. See Plunkr. https://plnkr.co/edit/kVgKIM?p=preview

```js
  (function() {
   'use strict';

   angular.module('testBenefits', ['ngRoute'])
   .controller('benefitsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.benefits = {
     "Emergency services": {
            "Emergency room care":{
              'name':'',
              'limit':'',
              'dlimit':''
            },
            "Ambulance service":{
              'name':'',
              'limit':'',
              'dlimit':''
            },
            "Urgent care centers/facilities":{
              'name':'',
              'limit':'',
              'dlimit':''
            }
        },
        "Laboratory services": {
            "Lab tests & X-ray services":{
              'name':'',
              'limit':'',
              'dlimit':''
            },
            "Imaging/diagnostics (e.g.,  MRI, CT scan, PET scan":{
              'name':'',
              'limit':'',
              'dlimit':''
            }
        },
    };

    $scope.showItems = function() {
     console.log($scope.benefits);
    };
    
   }]);

  })();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 </script>
 <title>Testing Benefits</title>
</head>
<body class="" ng-app="testBenefits" ng-controller="benefitsCtrl">
 <div class="container" ng-repeat="(key, benefit) in benefits">
  <h3 ng-model="planBenefit.category">{{key}}</h3>
  <table class="table">
   <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in benefit">
    <td ng-model="value.name">{{key}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="value.limit"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="value.dlimit"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <button ng-click="showItems()">Show Values</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun Shinde, that I see works but it is not exactly what I want. The array am using to construct the form fields am getting from an API different from the one am sending the data to. You have added another array into the array elements that I have. When am sending the data to the backend I send it as  {
     plan: "newPlan",
     category: "",
     benefit: "",
     limit: "",
     limit_individual: "",
     max_day_limit: ""
    }

Comment: I hope this helps you understand what am trying to achieve more because I cannot change the data formart that the API expects to receive

Comment: Why not you set data in your format on ng-click? You already achieved what you want.

Comment: As it is now it's not printing the name of the benefit but I will mimic what you have done to try achieve what I need. My point was that I cannot add elements to the original array in the before I display them. I needed to add those element on the go as I display the array values and capture them later on